# Driving Motorcycles in Mexico City with Indian License

Tags: indian-citizens, mexico

I will be travelling to Mexico City in the near future by holding work visa. Since I have only Indian Motorcycles license is it possible to drive motorcycles with Indian Motorcycles license if not what is the procedure to get the Mexican motorcycle license as a Expats.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't find an authoritative source, so take this with the appropriate grains of salt, but it appears to be the case that you can drive in Mexico with a foreign driver's license until it expires.

Once your license does expire, or if you want to buy a vehicle in Mexico, or really just if you want to, you can obtain a Mexican driver's license. The procedure for this varies by state, but in Mexico City, the *secretaría de movilidad* handles such things. To obtain a class A license for driving cars, [no test is needed](https://www.semovi.cdmx.gob.mx/tramites-y-servicios/vehiculos-particulares/automovil/licencias/licencia-expedicion-nueva): you simply need identification (your temporary or permanent residence visa), proof of residence in CDMX or the State of Mexico, and payment (945 pesos as of this writing). Then, you can [schedule an appointment](https://app.semovi.cdmx.gob.mx/citas/inicio) at a [branch of the vehicular control and licenses department](https://www.semovi.cdmx.gob.mx/tramites-y-servicios/vehiculos-particulares/modulos-de-control-vehicular-y-licencias) or at a [treasury service center](https://tics.finanzas.cdmx.gob.mx/citas/public/citas).

However, to obtain a [class A1 license for driving a motorcycle](https://semovi.cdmx.gob.mx/tramites-y-servicios/vehiculos-particulares/motocicleta/licencia/expedicion-de-licencia-tipo-a1) or a [class A2 license for driving both motorcycles and cars](https://semovi.cdmx.gob.mx/tramites-y-servicios/vehiculos-particulares/motocicleta/licencia/expedicion-de-licencia-tipo-a1), there is a [test of motorcycle skills](https://www.semovi.cdmx.gob.mx/tramites-y-servicios/vehiculos-particulares/motocicleta/licencia/centros-evaluadores) which, in addition to the above steps, [you must register for and take](https://www.infobae.com/en/2022/04/08/cdmx-how-to-register-for-the-free-motorcycle-driving-course-and-obtain-a-vehicle-license/) before you can get your license.